# Input pattern rails not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, input

I have this `password_field`:

```
<%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password (6 characters minimum)", autocomplete: "off", :required => true, :pattern => ".{6,32}", :title => "6 characters minimum" %>
```

Which generate this code (same in dev & prod environment):

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="user_password" name="user[password]" pattern=".{6,32}" placeholder="Password (6 characters minimum)" required="required" title="6 characters minimum" type="password">
```

In development it works great if I enter a password < 6 characters it shows me a popup.

But in production it doesn't prevent the form to be submitted. 
How can be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is one of those `remote: true` Rails forms... in the case it's behaving differently on production than development, I would suspect a problem with your Javascript assets is coming up.  E.g., maybe you didn't precompile your javascript assets?

Comment: It is not a remote form and yes I have everything precompiled :/

Comment: Try manually checking the javascript across dev and production.  Failing that, check the HTML you're using.  If it's all the same, it should work the same.  Not super helpful I know.